# Reopen 'Benefits of Structured Logging vs basic logging'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, vote-to-reopen

[Benefits of Structured Logging vs basic logging](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/312197/52929)

I made a significant edit to make this question more appropriately scoped here and less "tell me why my coworker is wrong."

Reopen votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It had 3 reopen votes. I finished up the process.

Comment: Might be worth deleting some of the earlier comments related to its topicality and subsequent reopening.